# How to share a gradle configuration unter submodules

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-dependencies

my project have two modules but whenever I try to create a dependency from configuration on the submodule2 to a configuration on :submoduleA:first, the request fails with configuration is not declared in the descriptor for project, could not resolve project.

```
myProject
├ submoduleA
| ├ first
| | ├ build.gradle.kts : define configuration
| ├ second
| | ├ build.gradle.kts : define configuration
| ├ settings.gradle: include ':first', ':second'
| ├ build.gradle.kts: include ':first', ':second'
├ submodule2
| ├ build.gradle: implementation project(":submodule:first"), implementation project(":submodule:second")
| ├ settings.gradle: include ':submoduleA:first', ':submoduleA:second'
```

- expected the configuration to depend on the configuration on the other subproject but seems failing

Comment: what does "seems failing" mean? any error and/or  stack trace ?   we can see you have `settings.gradle.kts` files in both  submodule A and submodule2 : this means these are two separate projects , you cannot create dependencies in this way